# could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dblib (from versions: none) and No matching distribution found for dblib

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I want to use the face_recognition library on microsoft visual studio code using python 3.9.2, but it's requires dblib to install. but it always end up with ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1. Right now i'm trying it with anaconda, but now the problem is always end up like this [ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dblib (from versions: none) and ERROR: No matching distribution found for dblib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw9Qk.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of the module "[face_recognition](https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/)" :

> "Built using dlib’s state-of-the-art face recognition"

please install the module "[dlib](https://pypi.org/project/dlib/)":

If you receive the following message when installing "dlib", please install the module "cmake": `pip install cmake`

[image]

check "dlib": `pip show dlib`

[image]

Comment: @Farhan Randy Maulana 3IA13 -How are things going? Have you tried using "pip install dlib" instead of "pip install dblib" to install the module "dlib"?

Comment: thanks, but now the problem is, when installing dlib it's always fail to build wheel

Comment: @Farhan Randy Maulana 3IA13 -Please try to reinstall the module "cmake" in the current python environment.

Comment: @Farhan Randy Maulana 3IA13 -How are things going? If my answer solves the problem, please [mark it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as an answer to help others find this solution.